# IFrame positioning Dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Currently working on IFrame but I am facing serious issue: I am creating a Iframe where i am placing  my Chat service so that I could use this service on other projects and want to have fixed position in my other projects that is right bottom of other projects page:
here is how I am using my script in other projects:

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Collaborative Text Editor</title>


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.src = 'http://localhost:4000/#/';
        iframe.width = '315px';
        iframe.height = '380px';
        iframe.style.top='40px'
    </script>

My Paragraph

  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

this line of code

```
  <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = 'http://localhost:4000/#/';
    iframe.width = '315px';
    iframe.height = '380px';
    iframe.style.top='40px'
</script>
```

here **`src`** is for testing purpose and IFrame styles is not working plus I want a fixed position always that is the right bottom of div concluding this:
I want a script with IFrame that has fixed position i.e want to embed this script on other pages or website with static position that is right bottom 
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want it in a fixed position, why aren't you setting the `position` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you forgot to add a position property.
Try this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com';
iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
iframe.style.bottom='1%'
iframe.style.right='1%'
iframe.width = '315px';
iframe.height = '380px';
</script>
```